# How to put an object's property to a href in AJAX?

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, href

I have a small question. How to put an object's property to href.
I marked with comment the line

```
success: function (listOfTags) {
        let tagData = '';
        $.each(listOfTags, function (i, tag) {
            // ON THE NEXT LINE
            tagData += '<a href="http://localhost:5557/questions/tagged/" ???tag.id><li class="post-tag">' + tag.name + '</li></a>';
        });

        $('#recentTags').html(tagData);
    }
```

Comment: And what's the actual problem? You already add `tag.name`. It's the same for any other property of `tag`.

Comment: The generated markup is invalid. An `<li />` element can only be a child of an `<ul />` element

Comment: It 's not concatenating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tagData += `<a href="http://localhost:5557/questions/tagged/${tag.id}"><li class="post-tag">${tag.name}</li></a>`;
```

For a valid markup, the anchor should be inside the list item, and the latter should be the child of a `ul` like this:

```
//before the loop
tagData += '<ul>';

tagData += `<li class="post-tag"><a href="http://localhost:5557/questions/tagged/${tag.id}">${tag.name}</a></li>`;

//after the loop
tagData += '</ul>';
```

Comment: What have you changed? And especially why, because OP already has `tag.name` in the string?

Comment: @Andreas Appending the tag id in the ``href`` string is the main issue

Comment: Which is just another string concatenation like with `tag.name` - which OP already does.

Comment: @NursD You are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution if it solved your problem.